# Receiving, "An error was thrown and was not caught: The validation data provided must contain ..." when creating a Text Classifier Model with CreateML

Tags: validation, text-classification, createml

I am using Playground to create a Text Classifier Model using CreateML and keep getting the error:

```
Playground execution terminated: An error was thrown and was not caught:
▿ The validation data provided must contain class.
  ▿ type : 1 element
    - reason : "The validation data provided must contain class."
```

My code is relatively simple, using two columns from a data table. The textColumn is labeled "text" and the labelColumn is labeled "class":

```
import Cocoa
import CreateML

let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/ ... .csv"))
let(trainingData, testingData) = data.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 5)
let sentimentClassifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: trainingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "class")
let evaluationMetrics = sentimentClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "class")
let evaluationAccuracy = (1.0 - evaluationMetrics.classificationError) * 100
```

The only difference I can find between this and the code provided in the Apple Developer Documentation is that instead of

```
let evaluationMetrics = sentimentClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "class")
```

their documentation is:

```
let evaluationMetrics = sentimentClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData)
```

and version 11.2.1 of Xcode gives me a failure if I try using the line from the Apple Developer Documentation.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This! it works for me

```
let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/justinmacbook/Desktop/twitter-sanders-apple3.csv"))

let (trainingData, testingData) = data.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 5 )

let sentimentClassifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: trainingData, textColumn: "class", labelColumn: "text")

let evaluationMetrics = sentimentClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData, textColumn: "class", labelColumn: "text")

let evaluationAccuracy = (1.0 - evaluationMetrics.classificationError) * 100
```

Comment: Format the code properly please so it is actually readable and easy to understand for other( including future users)

Comment: That worked @PrinceRana. The only issue was that I had the textColumn and labelColumn labels swapped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me. I believe this original code will only work on OSX 10.15+

```swift
import Cocoa
import CreateML
import NaturalLanguage

let data = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/m0a04y6/Desktop/iOS/ML/twitter-sanders-apple3.csv"))

let (trainingData, testingData) = data.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 5)
    
let parameters = MLTextClassifier.ModelParameters.init(validationData: trainingData, algorithm: MLTextClassifier.ModelAlgorithmType.maxEnt(revision: 1), language: NLLanguage.english, textColumnValidationData: "text", labelColumnValidationData: "class")
let sentimentClassifier = try MLTextClassifier(trainingData: trainingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "class", parameters: parameters)

let evaluationMetrics = sentimentClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "class")     //Training accuracy as a percentage

let evaluationAccuracy = (1.0 - evaluationMetrics.classificationError) * 100
print(evaluationAccuracy)

let metadata = MLModelMetadata(author: "Madhur Ahuja", shortDescription: "A model trained to classify movie review sentiment", version: "1.0")
try sentimentClassifier.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/m0a04y6/Desktop/iOS/ML/sentiment.mlmodel"), metadata: metadata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let (trainingData, testingData) = data.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 5)

let sentimentClassifier = try MLTextClassifier(
  trainingData: trainingData,
  textColumn: "text",
  labelColumn: "class"
)

let evaluationMetrics   = sentimentClassifier.evaluation(on: testingData, textColumn: "text", labelColumn: "class")

let evaluationAccuracy = (1.0 - evaluationMetrics.classificationError) * 100
```